# The difference between the 6 debug function modes of the Pycharm development tool?

Tags: python-3.x, ide, pycharm

Question 1. Details the shortcut keys

**(F8):** Step by step debugging. What are the special features and scene applications?

**(F7):** What is the difference between step-by-step debugging and F8 function? What are the special features and scene applications?

**(alt+shift+F7):** It can also be debugged step by step, as if you can skip the entire loop directly, what special features and scene applications are there.

**(shift+F8):** It feels like the end function function, but it seems to only end the loop or function, etc., and what special features and scene applications want to inform.

**( alt+F9):** It should be run directly to the mouse position.

**(F9):** Code reset, F9 seems to be reset debugging, but some people on the Internet said to enter the next paragraph of code debugging, I tried not seeming.
What is the difference between the above 6 kinds of debugging.... Especially the first two I feel no difference. I hope that good people can introduce through typical code examples and screenshots... Thanks.

Question 2.The (alt+shfit+F7) button is grayed out and cannot be used. Why? This function should be code reverse debugging!

Screenshot of the problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISLx9.png)

Comment: Have you tried reading PyCharm's help, which explains all those actions? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window.html#steptoolbar

Comment: sorry！English is too difficult to understand, I need a demo！

Comment: A StackOverflow answer will also be a text in English, not a demo.